# Calling Account Manager inside preference settings in android

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am trying to get the Switch account settings implemented inside PreferenceScreen similar to Google maps. How do I call the ACCOUNT MANAGER list dialog to show up from (inside) preference list in settings?

I am totally blank on this part?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Tanis.7x I am not sure what is the intent I need to call via prefence?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AccountManager: How to let the user select an Account using a Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406535/accountmanager-how-to-let-the-user-select-an-account-using-a-dialog)

Comment: @Tanis.7x How can this be duplicate I am asking on how to show the account Manger using Preference settings.. The link you have shared shows how to show a dialog through activity. Which is not what I want? Please read and understand my question again!

Comment: How is that different? Your preferences screen is an Activity, is it not?

Comment: It is preferenceFragement. Anyways. I would like to directly set the intent in preference.xml not via activty

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. Not only is there no such Intent, you also need to be able to handle the result of the user picking an account in `onActivityResult()`.