# Pass Selected Account to other activities

Tags: android, accountmanager

In my android application I use account manager. If there are multiple accounts, I ask to the user to select one account using [accountManager.newChooseAccountIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20425072/1584778). How can I remember this selection for the next time in login form and other activities?

Comment: use shared preferences to store this info http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: @cck, You can mark answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

**1. Launch the intent to show account selection dialog to the user-**

```
public static final int CHOOSE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
private String mEmail; 

Intent intent = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
    new String[] { acc_type }, true, null, null, null, null);
startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**2. Get the result inside onActivityResult -**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent   
data) {
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        mEmail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // The account picker dialog closed without selecting an account.
        // Notify users that they must pick an account to proceed.

    }
}

}
```

**3. You can then store the mEmail in Shared Preference to access within the
  application:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =    
context.getSharedPreferences("app_pref", MODE_PRIVATE);

editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

editor.putBoolean("Email", mEmail);

editor.commit();
```

**4. To access the stored email from shared preference:**

```
String email = sharedPreferences.getString("Email", "Use a default value");
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I had something similar in my mind before the asking question. Should I loop in account array with checking this email equality to get the authToken in every action or is there a easier way?

Comment: There is a post which explained a different approach with looping on accounts [Here's the link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15988448/2412582)